# I'm getting ESLINT warnings when declaring more than one private class method in JS, why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, es6-class

If I declare just one private method in a class then ESLINT compiles with no warnings, but...
ESLINT emits one extra warning for each new private method I declare in that same class.

For instance, ESLINT emits 2 warnings for a classe declared like this:

```js
class Clazz {
  #methodOne() { /*...*/ }
  #methodTwo() { /*...*/ }
  #methodThree() { /*...*/ }
}
```

ESLINT output:

```
WARNING  Compiled with 1 warning                                                                                                                                   10:14:26 PM

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/Users/***/Clazz.js
  3:3  error  Duplicate name ''  no-dupe-class-members
  4:3  error  Duplicate name ''  no-dupe-class-members

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or should I just ignore these warnings.

---

package.json:

```json
{
  //...
  "eslint": "^6.7.2",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
  //...
}
```

Comment: In javascript, `#` isn't a valid part of declaring class methods but I don't think that's the error it would give. So what information have you not given? Is it specific to some framework?

Comment: I'm not an experts but it seems to be part of ES6 syntax.
I learned about them on MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: Huh. I've never seen these used in the wild. Learn something new. I took a look at the spec for private members and ESLint's support of same. Do you have a config for eslint and babel? If so, can you share them? If not, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385125/eslint-does-not-recognize-private-field-declaration-using-nodejs-12) might help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found a workaround. Define your private methods like this:

```
class Clazz {
  #methodOne = function() { /*...*/ }
  #methodTwo = function() { /*...*/ }
  #methodThree = function() { /*...*/ }
}
```

and the linter warnings/errors will go away.